# Tag - How to set required for Tag it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tag-it

Im using [Jquery Tag it](http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/) for my tag function and save value to DB.

Using jquery how to set `myTags` required and at least one tag else not able to proceed/save. Reason is `<li>` and `<input>` are auto generate.

**HTML Code**

```
<ul id="myTags" name="myTags"></ul>
```

**Jquery**

```
$("#myTags").tagit({
    fieldName: "tags[]"
});
```

**ScreenShot**

[image]

Comment: Can you post more context?

Comment: @IonicăBizău there is all I have, that why I confusing now and asking help from here.

Comment: @IonicăBizău this tag inside a form, i want this tag be a required field,if I no key in any data, form should not be post. But the code of `tag it` very less, I have no idea where to set required

Comment: I posted an answer. Hope you find it useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>TagIt library [doesn't seem to provide an API for getting the list of tags](https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it/issues/254). However, you can read the HTML and see if tags are there.</strike>

On form submit, count the tags and `return false` if data is not valid. Use [`.tagit("assignedTags")`](https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it/blob/master/README.markdown#assignedtags) to get the list of tags:

```
var $tags = $("#myTags");
$tags.tagit({
    fieldName: "tags[]"
});

$("form").on("submit", function () {
    if (!$tags.tagit("assignedTags").length) {
        alert("Tags are mandatory");
        return false;
    }
    alert("Valid data");
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/rmov1ruv/1/)

Comment: Thanks !! this `if ($tags.find("li").length <= 1) {
        alert("Tags are mandatory");
        return false;
    }` are totally what I'm look for ! Give you million LIKE =)

Comment: Cool, note that it's better to use the tagit API. You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the assignedTags() method https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it/blob/master/README.markdown#assignedtags to check how many tags have been assigned and then move forward based on that. I guess for you something like this will work

```
if($("#myTags").tagit("assignedTags").length>0){
    //submit form
}
else{
    alert("please add at least one tag");
}
```